# Enable plugin on custom page in nopCommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, nopcommerce

I have to develop a widget plugin and must be active only on a certain page. I went throw the tutorials on creating a plugin, but I didn't figure it out how to make the widget visible only on a certain page. Is this possible?
Where do I have to make the changes for this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: by making it active on a 'certain page', do you mean that it's visible in the sidebar only on a certain page or is this a central content feature??

Comment: an example is a tracking code for tracking sales, or on the sing-up only on the sing-up page

Comment: at a very 'simple' level, I'd just have different templates for those functional areas and add the widget(s) as required into those templates.

Comment: I want the plugin to work only for the 'Home Page', where do I have to   point that in the code, that the site loads the plugin only when 'Home Page' is requested.

Comment: just create a brand new template that only your home page points to and you're good to go. as i said, this would be the simplest way to operate and bearing in mind that very often the 'homepage' has significantly different requirements to the sub sections, this may make sense anyway. good luck and keep us posted

Comment: what do you mean by creating a "new template that only your home page points to" after going throw the tutorials I must create a class library project in the "Plugins" folder and then add the components that make that respective plugin, my problem is that I don't know were to modify in the code to activate the plugin only on the "Home page" if the user goes to another page the plugin will not work , I want to implement a tracking script in javascript only for the "Home Page"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22588/discussion-between-xandruu-and-jim-tollan)

Comment: hey, sorry didn't see comment. afraid i can't really spawn out to chat as working on delivery item at present. however, I will come back to this either over the weekend or beginning next week

Answer (score 2):

It is possible by doing (either/both) the following:

1. Some widget zones are page specific. Add to the widget zones that are specific to a page and it'll only be shown on that page.
2. When serving the widget, you can get the HttpContext, which you then can get the route data. By examining the route data, you then can decide which page you are currently in, and optionally show the widget.

Hope this helps. :)